# pdflatex: Command for pdflatex gave return code 1, but not error in log file

Tags: errors, compilation-error

When I build my project using a Makefile I get this:

```
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on build/report.pdf (51 pages).
SyncTeX written on build/report.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on build/report.log.
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: Index file 'build/report.idx' was written
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'build/report.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'build/report.pdf'
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [bibliography.bib build/report.bcf]
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'build/report.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
make: *** [Makefile:20: all] Error 12
```

After 3-4 times repeating `make`, I eventually get this:

```
$ make
latexmk -pdf
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

My `.latexmkrc` is the following:

```
system ("mkdir -p build/figures");

@default_files = ('report.tex');
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "glo gls 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].glo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].gls"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'glo');

# Custom dependency and function for nomencl package
  add_cus_dep( 'nlo', 'nls', 0, 'makenlo2nls' );
  sub makenlo2nls {
  system( "makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \"$_[0].nls\" \"$_[0].nlo\"" );
}

$out_dir = 'build';
$pdflatex = 'xelatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape';
$latex = 'latex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape';
```

When I look at the `build/report.log` I don't see any error.

Why is my problem?

Comment: Try running the `pdflatex` (or `xelatex`) command alone without `make` or `latexmk`. What do you see?

Comment: I see no errors :(

Comment: Then? Does the command error out?

Comment: I mean if you use nonstopmode it would be hard to distinguish error anyway? Check the return code?